# Which Thread Does QML Functions run in?

Tags: qt, qml

I wonder that does qml functions run in main thread?

Connection between c++ signal and qml slot direct or queued?

Comment: I don't think there's a simple answer to this. There are different types of bindings, for example. But yes mostly it runs in the "main/GUI" thread, like most (all?) applications with a user interface have to. Study https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-performance.html for optimization tips and some technical details.

Answer (score 0):

qml functions runs in mainloop. take a look here:
https://marketplace.qt.io/products/main-loop-wdt-for-qt-qml

About C ++ signals and QML slots, I'm not sure. I assume it is a Qt::AutoConnection, but I am using proxy signals:

```
signals:
void dateChanged();
void _dateChanged();
...
  connect(this,&Utils::_dateChanged,this,&Utils::dateChanged, Qt::QueuedConnection );
..
QtConcurrent::run([=]() {
...
  emit _dateChanged();
});
```

Both options work:

```
      Utils{
            id:utils
            onDateChanged: { //DIRECT CONNECTION
                console.log("FROM MAINLOOP CHANGED")
            }
            on_DateChanged: { //QUEUED CONNECTION ??
                console.log("FROM THREAD CHANGED")
            }
        }
```